# SQL bulk insert does not insert values properly into table

Tags: .net, excel, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlbulkcopy

I have an Excel file(.xlsx) and I am trying to upload the content of the file into a Sql server table. Iam using the SQL bulk copy to bulk insert the data. The data gets inserted into the table but I find that the data is not inserted properly.

Here is the sample Excel data-

[image]

This is the code for Sql bulk copy:

```
string fname = Path.GetFileName(fup_addRoute.FileName);
fup_addRoute.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/Admin/UserRoutes/" + fname));
string path = Server.MapPath("/Admin/UserRoutes/" + fname);
                    
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", path)))
{
      OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);
      connection.Open();
      System.Data.Common.DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();
      SqlBulkCopy bulkInsert = new SqlBulkCopy(con); 
      bulkInsert.DestinationTableName = "routesdata";
      bulkInsert.WriteToServer(dr);
      connection.Close();
      dr.Close();
      bulkInsert.Close();
}
```

Data after insert:

[image]

Only last row gets inserted and the first column value in excel sheet is missing. The xid column in table is an auto-increment column.

This procedure was easy in MySql with 'load data infile' but I just migrated to Sql server. What am I doing wrong in my code. Suggestions please.

Comment: Are you only getting the last row or just not receiving the 1st row?

Comment: Sorry, I just found that I am only missing the first row.

Comment: Try adding HDR=NO to your connection string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm actually a bit surprised you are not reporting an exception.

At any rate, I suspect that (at least part of) your problem is that you need to specify the column mappings.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopycolumnmapping.aspx

> If mappings are not defined—that is, the ColumnMappings collection is empty—the columns are mapped implicitly based on ordinal position. For this to work, source and target schemas must match. If they do not, an InvalidOperationException will be thrown.

From what I can see your Excel file and your database tables do **not** match on all columns (e.g. the auto-increment).  So I would try specifying your [column mappings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings.aspx).

Comment: just a guess that first roa i

Comment: Sorry about top comment. It was a mistake.  Sorry

Comment: Great, your solution solved the issue with auto increment field. Thanks. Oh now who's answer do I accept, sdegges solved one and you solved the other issue.

Answer (score 3):

As a follow-up to my earlier comment, since you're only missing the first row, it sounds like you need to add `HDR=No` to your connection string.

It should look something like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No';
```

--EDIT

Please note the added apostrophes.

Good luck.

Comment: Sorry that generates an exception after adding HDR=No; `Could not find installable ISAM.`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512143/error-could-not-find-installable-isam/512187#512187

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/644365/1073631 -- see if that doesn't help -- I just copied and pasted :)

Comment: +1 that solved the issue of missing the first row. However I still have the issue with auto increment.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  Not sure I'm understanding your other issue.

Comment: You can see the screen shots in the question. The value `a1_sec-ecil` isn't inserted in the table and the radius column was inserted with null which should be 3 (as per the example)

Comment: Nathan's answer solved the issue with autoincrement filed. Confused who's answer to accept :)

Comment: No worries -- glad we could help.