# Error connecting to excel

Tags: c#, .net, database-connection, oledb, export-to-excel

I need to programmatically read Microsoft Excel file from a specific path. The following code results in an error message I have never seen before

```
string sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("Book1.xls") + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes"; 
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
        con.Open();
```

While opening the connection, the following error message is shown:

```
Could not find installable ISAM.
```

Does anybody have a solution related to this error? I would appreciate your help in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644331/open-an-excel-2003-spreadsheet-with-c-could-not-find-installable-isam-excepti), you have to enclose the properties in quotes and make sure the path doesn't contain spaces.

Change your code to

```
string sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("Book1.xls") + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes'";
```