# ASP.NET: "Could not find installable ISAM" exception when trying to read dBASE IV file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, connection-string, dbase, isam

I need to open and read a Dbase file in my ASP.NET application. When I try to open the connection, I am getting the exception "Could not find installable ISAM." I have tried the solutions in the top answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512143/error-could-not-find-installable-isam), but they did not work for me.

The filepath of the data file is C:\dev\DATA.DBF. Here is the code I am using to try to open the connection:

```
Dim connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=C:\dev\DATA.DBF;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;"
Dim connection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
connection.Open()
```

At this point I get the exception "Could not find installable ISAM." Do you have any ideas what I can try to get this to work? Note that I am able to import this file into an Access database as a dBASE IV file.

I am running Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7. Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem. I used the technique outlined in [this post](http://aspcode.net/reading-dbf-files-in-c).

I am using an ODBC connection instead of an OLE connection. Here is the code:

```
Dim connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=C:\dev;Exclusive=No; Collate=Machine;NULL=NO;DELETED=NO;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;"
Dim connection As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnnection(connectionString)
Dim command As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM C:\dev\DATA.DBF", connection)
connection.Open()
Dim reader As OdbcDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
connection.Close()
```

Note that the directory name of the DBF file is in the connection string, while the full path of the DBF file is in the select statement. I simply followed the convention in the linked post, and it worked for me.

Comment: +1 for finding a working solution and posting it here (as opposed to deleting the question, as some people do).