# Could not find installable ISAM

Tags: c#, oledb

I have the following code :

```
string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\db\suc.xls; Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;""";

// Create Connection to Excel Workbook
using (OleDbConnection connection =
             new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString))
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand
            ("Select * FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);

    connection.Open();
```

and i get the following error :

> Could not find installable ISAM.

at `connection.Open()` . Any ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Could not find installable ISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562267/system-data-oledb-oledbexception-could-not-find-installable-isam)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no 64 bit version of the Jet OLEDB drivers, so if you are running this on a 64 bit OS you might need to target `x86` in your .NET application and not `Any CPU`:

[image]

Comment: I fixed this issue by putting quotes around the data source. See answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512143/error-could-not-find-installable-isam/512187#512187

Comment: I had the same error, and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18307822/426315) is how I've fixed it

Comment: This did not fix my problem as well.

Comment: did not fix mine too

Answer (score 22):

I had the same error, but none of the suggestions above worked. In my case all I had to do was to change my connection string to this:

```
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;'";
```

Note the Single Quote around the Extended Properties attribute ('Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;'). Once I added those single quotes the error disappeared!

Comment: This worked for me by putting all extended properties into the quotes ''

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this issue trying to opening an xls file with a more recent provider.
I fixed this issue by changing my extended properties from

```
Extended Properties="Excel 11.0;"
```

to

```
Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;"
```

I guess Excel 11 expects an xlsx style file.

Comment: Wow I was using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0 and I changed Excel 160 to 8.0 and worked fine Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On 64-bit Windows and 64-bit Office (2010, 2013) environments, there are many reports on this error. The fix or workaround is a bit strange but seems to work for most people out there.

The "[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13255)" installation package seems the natural one to use but several reports says it does not work.

Instead, using the "[2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734)" seems to solve the above problem for most people.

Answer (score 0):

use `Extended properties="\excel 8.0;`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem. I was using an Excel 2010 database. But I had a xlsx file instead of xls. I solved my problem using the connection string as fallows,

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=logbook.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;';

What I was missing are,
I used OLEDB.4.0 instead of ACE.12.0 . I tried using ACE.14.0. But it didn't work either. 
Then I missed inverted commas ( ' ' ) around Extended Properties.

Sorry if the answer is hard to read, I am uploading this in my phone.

Answer (score 0):

// SET A CONNECTION WITH THE EXCEL FILE.

```
              OleDbConnection myExcelConn = new OleDbConnection
                  ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " +
                      "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath(".") + "\\" + fileUpload1.FileName +
                      ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'");
```

Putting Single quote in Extended Properties like
Extended Properties ='Excel 12.0:HDR=YES'  solved my problem.