# Increase connection pool size in OLE DB connection string

Tags: c#, connection-string, oledb

I am attempting to increase the pool size in the connection string for an SSIS package that connects to an Access database on my desktop (holy run-on sentence...). I can not find the synatx for doing so, though. Could someone please fill me in? My current connection string looks like this:

```
"Provider=Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider;Data source= C:\\Users\\nearod\\Desktop\\ImportDB.accdb"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you use the `Max Pool Size` keyword in your connection string:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254502.aspx

Maybe try this:

`"Provider=Microsoft Office 12.0 Access Database Engine OLE DB Provider;Data source= C:\\Users\\nearod\\Desktop\\ImportDB.accdb;Max Pool Size=200"`

Note that the default is 100.  Also note that I've not tried this and am just referencing the MSDN documentation.

Comment: This threw the following exception: "Could not find installable ISAM"

Comment: What is your target platform?  Looks like there is no x64 driver for you, per this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214527/could-not-find-installable-isam

Comment: It is supposed to go into an SQL database. We are running Windows 7, 64 bit.

Comment: SQL database, or Access?  The connection string you put in your questions was for Access, not SQL Server.

Comment: Sorry, we are pulling data from an Access database and depositing it in the SQL database. We have assumed, since our DBA told us the connection time out is 600 seconds, that the time out was occurring while attempting to connect to the Access database.