# Unexpected error from external database driver (22)

Tags: c#

Here's my code which is in the beginning of a method for converting .xls file to .csv.

```
sourceFile="C:\\Users\\myUser\\Desktop\\Folder\\myFile.xls";

string strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sourceFile + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);

conn.Open();
```

And it crashes on the last line, throwing this exception: Unexpected error from external database driver (22).

I tried removing the IMEX=1 part, but it still didn't work.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide us that `myFile.xls` ?

Comment: @yogi It's an excell file with one sheet. The first row has two columns, and all the next have 9 columns. The cells have a background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strangely enough, I replaced the file in another folder and it worked. I have no idea why this is happening.

Comment: Your application needs to be able to open the file with administrator permissions. You probably moved the file to a folder where your application had that level of access.

Comment: I got this exception. And when I moved my excel file to a different folder, it worked.

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException. Unexpected error from external database driver 枰儛☐չ䔰疈

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same issue but I had to rename the spreadsheet to a shorter name, then it worked.(SQL 2012 Dev)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider. Also I would advise you to use `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` to build `OleDbConnectionString`:

```
var oleConnectionStringBuilder = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder { Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" };
oleConnectionStringBuilder.DataSource = sourceFile;
oleConnectionStringBuilder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 8.0");
oleConnectionStringBuilder.Add("HDR", "No");
```

Comment: With using your code I get Could not find installable ISAM. error.

Comment: @petko_stankoski Here is discussing about this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214527/could-not-find-installable-isam

Comment: @petko_stankoski, this thread contains possible solution too: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/62ee4978-ca29-48d3-9367-6dd4ab639d2d/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is something wrong with the Microsoft Excel Driver. Try to execute the program in another PC to see whether this error happens.

Please take a look at this KB article:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ReadExcel07.aspx . You can use OleDb to connect the Excel file.

I hope this can help you and feel free to follow up after you have tried.

Comment: Which program do I need to execute on another pc?

Comment: Your application, and keep the file on that PC.

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed this by uninstalling Microsoft access DB  Engine Security update.Also Uninstall Service pack3 Update of access DB engine 2007. Hope this will work...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I renamed excel file's sheet name(it was too long), after that it worked.
[image]

I'm using :

```
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml; IMEX=1;Importmixedtypes=text;\"";
```