# Cannot connect to excel from c#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-jet-ace

I want to connect to a .xlsx file from my ASP.NET application.

Here is my connection string:

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};Data Source=\"C:\\MyExcel.xlsx\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO\"";

OleDbConnection oleConnection = new OleDbConnection(connString);
```

But when I try to open the connection I get
**Could not find installable ISAM**

- Office version: 2007
- OS: windows 7 64 bit
- .NET framework 4.0
- Downloaded the **32 bit** ACE driver from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255

I even changed the platform target of my app to x86 but no success.

Please help!

Comment: Please check the following question and be sure to change platform target at exactly same place as on the screenshot there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214527/could-not-find-installable-isam

Comment: I guess one of the forum suggested to use a single code. Just give a try as like below. string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};Data Source='C:\\MyExcel.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO'";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the connection string to:

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"C:\\MyExcel.xlsx\";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO\"";
```

The `Driver=...` part is required when you are connecting using ODBC driver. When connecting using OLEDB, specifying the `Provider` is sufficient. Refer to [this page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) for more information.

Comment: @Shuaib there is a tickbox next to answers, mark correct ones as this saves people time letting them know your issue is resolved and it gives you a couple of points too. Good luck!