# could not find installable isam access #2

Tags: c#, ms-access, database-connection

I have a problem in my c# application that related to Connection string , as I think.

Scenarios:
I moved from login form to Main form, in loading I set the connection string, and all things fine.
When I closed Main form, and re-login in con.Open() step , this error release:
 could not find installable ISAM.

my connection String:

```
conString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=";
conString += Application.StartupPath + "//ShDB.mdb; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=2212123;";
```

Comment: Did you try solution from there?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214527/could-not-find-installable-isam

Comment: yeah, I did .. same problem