# Load excel to datagridview using vb.net as language and MySQL as Database

Tags: mysql, vb.net, excel, datagridview

I watched a tutorial and all codes where copied except for the path. But i get the error **Could not find installable ISAM** in the **cn.open()**

Here is the overall code:

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OlEDB.4.0; Data Source:G:\Book1.xlsx;Extend Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        cn.Open() <--Error Here

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet1$]", cn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        With DataGridView1
            .AllowUserToAddRows = False
            .DataSource = dt
        End With

        dt.Dispose()
        dt = Nothing
        da.Dispose()
        da = Nothing

        With cn
            .Close()
            .Dispose()
        End With
        cn = Nothing

    End Sub
    End Class
```

I hope anyone could help me. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not find installable ISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214527/could-not-find-installable-isam)

Comment: @WinterMute this cant be a duplicate because the solutions provided in the other questions didnt solved m problem. Im using VB.net not ASP and MySql not Access

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an .xlsx file, you need to use the ACE.OLDB.12.0 driver:

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=G:\Book1.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0"

Notice the Source is assigned using and "=" sign, not a colon ":"

Comment: @The 'Microsoft.ACE.OlEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine. any way to fix this?

Comment: ill stick to hearing out your solutions at least you had the time to suggest an answer to my question.

Comment: Download load it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255"