# “error isam instalable cant be found”

Tags: c#, dbf

I'm trying to connect my windows form app with my embedded database (.dbf) and I keep getting this message no matter what I do to the connection string:

> error isam instalable cant be found

Here is the code I'm using to test the whole thing:

```
private void bGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
    string cadena = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source =D:\\; Extended Properties = dBASE IV; UserID =; Password =;";
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = cadena;
    con.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("conected");
    con.Close();
    }
    catch (OleDbException exp)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("Error: " + exp.Message); 
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in the connection string.

Comment: Havent you asked this here already yesterday?

Comment: The second result when i plug your title into google: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512143/error-could-not-find-installable-isam

Comment: Did you install access 2007 or earlier engine on the machine? You might instead use VFPOLEDB driver. In either case you should target x86. Also note that it needs installation and not an embedded database.

Comment: looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512143/error-could-not-find-installable-isam