# importing excel data to database using asp.net and c #

Tags: c#, asp.net

am getting the following error while trying to import data from excel to the database.

> The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object
>   'C:\Users\DAKTARI\Desktop\smarttable.xls'

this is my code behind that am using.

```
 public partial class Smarttable : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    OleDbConnection Econ;
    SqlConnection con;

    string constr, Query, sqlconn;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void ExcelConn(string FilePath)
    {

        constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\DAKTARI\Desktop\smarttable.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""");
        Econ = new OleDbConnection(constr);

    }
    private void connection()
    {
        sqlconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlCom"].ConnectionString;
        con = new SqlConnection(sqlconn);

    }


    private void InsertExcelRecords(string FilePath)
    {
        ExcelConn(FilePath);

        Query = string.Format("Select [InvoiceNumber],[AmountPaid],[Remarks] FROM [C:\\Users\\DAKTARI\\Desktop\\smarttable.xls]", "Orders$");
        OleDbCommand Ecom = new OleDbCommand(Query, Econ);
        Econ.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(Query, Econ);
        Econ.Close();
        oda.Fill(ds);
        DataTable Exceldt = ds.Tables[0];
        connection();
        //creating object of SqlBulkCopy    
        SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
        //assigning Destination table name    
        objbulk.DestinationTableName = "smarttable";
        //Mapping Table column    
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("InvoiceNumber", "InvoiceNumber");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("AmountPaid", "AmountPaid");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("Remarks", "Remarks");
        //inserting Datatable Records to DataBase    
        con.Open();
        objbulk.WriteToServer(Exceldt);
        con.Close();

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CurrentFilePath = Path.GetFullPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
        InsertExcelRecords(CurrentFilePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: well the error seems pretty specific.....

Comment: Is this a timing error i.e. is the file upload still in progress as you attempt to open it?

Comment: no it is not in progress..i select the file but upon the upload i get the error.

Answer (score 1):

Your Excel file format uses XLS which means for Office 2003 or earlier, but you're using ACE OLEDB provider which used for Office 2007 or later:

```
constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\DAKTARI\Desktop\smarttable.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"");
```

The correct usage is using Jet 4.0 provider like this:

```
constr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;'", FilePath);
```

Also you have second issue which a wrong query string is used to read the data inside worksheet:

```
Query = string.Format("Select [InvoiceNumber],[AmountPaid],[Remarks] FROM [C:\\Users\\DAKTARI\\Desktop\\smarttable.xls]", "Orders$");
```

This should be changed to proper form below:

```
Query = "SELECT [InvoiceNumber],[AmountPaid],[Remarks] FROM [Orders$]";
```

Comment: thanks alot. am using excel 2016. i have corrected the ACE OLEDB to using jet 4.o but am now getting this error; could not find installable ISAM.

Comment: kindly assist me..its giving me a hell of time

Comment: Use single quotes for `Extended Properties` part instead of double ones, see the edited one (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512143/error-could-not-find-installable-isam).

Comment: i have done that and now am getting this error. Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 89.

Comment: kindly help me out am totally confused on this one

Comment: could my web.config also have a problem..   here is what i have on the web.config.    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>         <configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2" />
   
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>

Comment: According to https://yoursandmyideas.com/2011/02/05/how-to-read-or-write-excel-file-using-ace-oledb-data-provider/, seems that the connection string is valid even using single or double quotes in `Extended Properties`. What target platform you've used (x86 or x64)?

Comment: am using x64..i have not changed the target build platform but you can guide me on how to configure and check

Comment: Well, AFAIK JET OLEDB provider only work for x86 mode, so you need to set target build platform to x86 (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb4wyys2.aspx for Target CPU setting details).

Comment: its still not working and giving me the same error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 89"

Comment: i have changed my webconfig to this:  <configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SqlCom" connectionString ="Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SmartCare;Trusted_Connection=yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>

Comment: @johnkc Sorry for late reply. I edited with proper usage of `string.Format` (since you're using `FilePath` argument to supply Excel file path).

Comment: thanks Tetsuya Yamamoto..kindly send me the edited code you did kindly..am not getting it..please you will have saved me alot..

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Query = string.Format("Select [InvoiceNumber],[AmountPaid],[Remarks] FROM [C:\\Users\\DAKTARI\\Desktop\\smarttable.xls]", "Orders$");
```

To

```
Query = "Select [InvoiceNumber],[AmountPaid],[Remarks] FROM [Orders$]";
```

The `FROM` needs to be followed by the Sheet Name which is treated like a table