# Connecting to Excel file stored on SharePoint via ADODB

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I'm trying to query data from my workbook located on SharePoint using the following code (which I've been using successfully for years in workbooks stored on my hard drive):

```
Dim con As Object
Dim rcs As Object
Dim strConnection As String

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rcs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strConnection = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";HDR=Yes';"
Call con.Open(strConnection)
```

At this point, the following error is thrown:

*[Microsoft][ODBC Excel Driver] Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.*

In this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28434783/opening-excel-file-stored-on-sharepoint-as-data-source-using-adodb-connection), it was suggested to replace certain characters in the workbook's path, and they also used a different Provider. So I tried the following, which is pretty much copy pasted (and slightly cleaned up) from the last comment in that thread:

```
Private Sub ConnectToDatabase()
    Dim con As Object
    
    Dim strPath As String, strCon As String
    
    strPath = Convert_HTTP_To_NetworkPath(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strPath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    Call con.Open(strCon)

End Sub


Function Convert_HTTP_To_NetworkPath(strPath As String) As String
    
    strPath = Replace(strPath, " ", "%20")
    strPath = Replace(strPath, "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com", "\\mycompany.sharepoint.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot")
    strPath = Replace(strPath, "/", "\")
    If IsIn(".", Right(strPath, 5)) = False And Right(strPath, 1) <> "\" Then strPath = strPath & "\"
    Convert_HTTP_To_NetworkPath = strPath
    
End Function

Function IsIn(strKeyword As String, strText As String)

    If UCase(strText) Like "*" & UCase(strKeyword) & "*" Then IsIn = True Else IsIn = False
    
End Function
```

Resulting in this error:

*Method 'Open' of object '_Connection' failed.*

Using my original connection string (with the cleaned workbook path) only brought back the first error.

Following the advice in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66660519/is-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-the-right-connection-string-for-microsoft-excel-365), I also tried this connection string:

```
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0; Data Source=" & strPath & "; Extended Properties='Excel 16.0 XLSM; HDR=Yes; IMEX=1';"
```

Which yieled yet another error:

*Could not find installabe ISAM.*

The workbook path does not contain any special characters, and the file is saved as xlsm.

Comment: Does it work if you manually replace `ThisWorkbook.FullName` with the local path of your file? If yes, I recommend converting the WebPath into a local path using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72736924/12287457) function, by copying the code into your module and using the function like so: `GetLocalPath(ThisWorkbook.FullName)`