# Reading data from shared teams text file using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, text-files, connection-string, adodb

I have created a tool using VBA that performs several pulls from BigQuery and does a variety of transformations and summarization inside of Excel. The tool is an evolving tool and to make sure that the users are using the most current version of the tool, I would like to have a version file saved on the shared Teams page that the tool would check and if needed, download the newest version onto the tool to the user's folder. I have scrubbed the web for several solutions to this ask but not one that actually works. Below are the links to the solutions I have attempted. The issue is that the connectors for opening text files seem to not work with a URL from Teams. I need to know how to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html

*This solution doesn't seem to work with a URL as I get a Bad Filename error.*

https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/download-file-from-sharepoint-and-save-it-in-system-folder.41779/

*Problem with this one is that the download for some reason shows completed but actually never moves local.*

[Connecting to Excel file stored on SharePoint via ADODB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72198459/connecting-to-excel-file-stored-on-sharepoint-via-adodb)
https://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile/

*I attempted to use this solution using the text file connection string but was not successful here either.*

https://www.exceltip.com/import-and-export-in-vba/import-data-from-a-text-file-ado-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html

*Again, another bad name error.*

Any help or advice on how to connect to a simple text file shared in a Teams folder would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So if I got it right, you want to store the tool version number in a text file on Teams, so that the tool can perform a version check against it and if it finds that a new version is available, update itself, is that right?

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to accomplish.